# Envers: wrong audit table on a Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm using `Spring Data JPA 1.6.4` with `Hibernate 4.3.6.Final` + `envers` into a `Spring MVC 4.0.7` web application secured with `Spring Security 3.2.5`. The web application is deployed on a Tomcat 7.0.52
 web container, configured with a JNDI datasource:

```
<Resource 
              name="jdbc/appDB"
              auth="Container" 
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              initialSize="4"
              maxActive="8"
              maxWait="10000"
              maxIdle="8"
              minIdle="4"
              username="user"
              password="password" 
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
              url="jdbc:mysql://ip/schema?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" 
              testOnBorrow="true" 
              testWhileIdle="true" 
              validationQuery="select 1"
              validationInterval="300000" />
```

Database runs on a MySql Server version 5.5 and have an InnoDB schema.

I have a strange behaviour with audit table `Customers_H`: noticed that **sometimes** audit tables are populated in a wrong way by `envers`. The most of the time things works ok.

I have no idea of why and when It happens, but I have as a result of an insert a revision table like the following:

```
ID        ACTION TYPE        REV END        USER
23              0               256          U1
23              2               NULL        NULL
23              0               NULL         U2
```

The strange thing is that U1 is the owner of an entity with id = 6 (not of the entity with id = 23!), while U2 has really worked on entity ID 23. The problem is that the revision table is inconsinstent and then I have an Hibernate ASSERTION FAILURE.

Seems that it should be ok only if envers creates the third row. But why it creates also the first (with action CREATE) and the second one (with action DELETE)?

```
ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot update previous revision for entity Customer_H and id 23.
```

This prohibit user to update the entity.

My problem is to investigate how this can happen!

Here is `Customer` domain:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Audited
public class Customer extends AbstractDomain{

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(updatable=false, nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Company company;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Plant> plants = new HashSet<Plant>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private CustomerType customerType;

    private String code;

    // other basic fields + getter and settes
}
```

And `Company` domain have a reverse mapping to `Customer`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
```

Here is `AbstractDomain` class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public abstract class AbstractDomain implements Auditable<String, Long>, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    

    @Version
    @JsonIgnore
    private int version;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private String createdBy;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private DateTime createdDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @JsonIgnore
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }
    @Override
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    @Override
    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }
    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }
    @Override
    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @Transient
    @Override
    public final boolean isNew() {
        if (id == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is `CustomerService`:

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService{

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Override
    @PostAuthorize("@customerSecurityService.checkAuth(returnObject)")
    public Customer findById(Long id) {
        return customerRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public Customer create(Customer entry) {
        entry.setCompany(SecurityUtils.getCustomer().getCompany());
        return customerRepository.save(entry);
    }

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("@customerSecurityService.checkAuth(#entry)")
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public Customer update(Customer entry) {
        return customerRepository.save(entry);
    }

    ....
}
```

Here is my `CustomerRepository`

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long>,  QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Customer> {

}
```

Here the Service I use to do security checks in `@PreAuthorize` `@PostAuthorize` annotations in `CustomerService` methods:

```
@Component
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomerSecurityService {

    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerSecurityService.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public boolean checkAuth(Customer customer) {
        if(customer == null) {
            LOGGER.error("customer NULL!");
            return false;
        }


        if (customer.getId()==null) {
            return true;
        }


        if (customer.getId()!=null) {
            Customer dbCustomer = customerRepository.findOne(customer.getId());

            if (dbCustomer.getCompany().getId().equals( SecurityUtils.getCustomer().getCompany().getId())){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkPage(Page<Customer> pages) {
        for(Customer customer : pages.getContent()) {
            Customer dbCustomer = customerRepository.findOne(customer.getId());

            if (!dbCustomer.getCompany().getId().equals(SecurityUtils.getCustomer().getCompany().getId())){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My `SecurityUtils` class

```
public class SecurityUtils {

    private SecurityUtils(){}

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityUtils.class);

    public static Customer getCustomer() {
        Customer customer = null;
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()!=null) {
            customer = ((User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getCustomer();
            LOGGER.debug("Customer found: "+customer.getUserName());
        }else {
            LOGGER.debug("Customer not bound.");
        }
        return customer;        
    }


    public static boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally xml jpa configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="scan.domain"/>

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <!--${hibernate.format_sql} -->
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <!-- ${hibernate.show_sql} -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop> 

                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>

                <prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>

                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_H</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name">ACTION_TYPE</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy">org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp">True</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name">AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS</prop>               
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="scan.repository"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorAwareBean" />

    <bean id="auditorAwareBean" class="auditor.AuditorAwareBean"/>

</beans>
```

In the project I have about 50 domain classes, some of them with Inheritance `SINGLE_TABLE`.

The application is now used by few users, that are not connected at the same time. So I can say that only one user is using my application at a given time.

I also not understand how can I make an unsafe use of the `Session`. I never work directly with Hibernate Session. I always use a higher level abstraction with Spring Data Repositories. Sometimes I need to extends `JpaRepository` interface in order to call `saveAndFlush()` or explicitly call `flush()`. Maybe that the cause?

I can't understand this behaviour! Any suggestion would be appreciated!!

Comment: Your camparison and storage of the user seems fishy. You might endup adding the company to another user while the old user is still part of the old Company. This is due to the fact you are working with detached instances and maybe attached instances. That might introduce problems.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum! So in your opinion the problem could be in CustomerSecurityService? Here I check if the Customer (stored in SecurityContextHolder) is the owner of the entity and if he can update it. To check the entity I get it from the db (the entity is coming from an update in the view and I do not map not updatable fields to an hiddden). Then I compare them. If I understand your comment you are saying that query for the entity in the db in order to compare it before proceed to save is the problem, I'm right?

Comment: @M.Deinum are you refer this issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HHH-6361?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubles I have found the solution:

mysql 5.5 guide states:

> InnoDB uses the in-memory auto-increment counter as long as the server
>   runs. When the server is stopped and restarted, InnoDB reinitializes
>   the counter for each table for the first INSERT to the table, as
>   described earlier.

This is a big problem for me. I'm using envers to keep entities audits. I get as many errors as many "last rows" I delete.

Suppose I'm starting insert data into an empty table. Suppose to insert 10 rows. Then suppose to delete the last 8. In my db I will have as result 2 entities, with id 1 and 2 respectively. In the audit table I will have all 10 entities, with id from 1 to 10, and entities with id from 3 to 10 will have 2 action: create action and delete action.

auto-increment counter is now setted to 11. Restarting mysql service auto-increment counter goes to 3. So if I insert a new entity, it will be saved with id 3. But in audit table there is also an entity with id = 3. That entity is already marked as created and deleted. It result in an assertion failure during update /delete action because envers cannot handle this inconsistent state.

Comment: You said you found a solution but... What is it? I am facing a similar problem at this moment :-/

Comment: Yes.. solution is not the proper word. I've found why this happens. A solution could be to execute a scripts that sets for each table autoincrement base value eq to max+1 of relative audit table.

Comment: @Kazbeel obviously you need to this operation only when restart of mysql service occurs.. hope this helps!

Comment: For solution please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61157228/1785788